# Django: Loop over 2 objects in same loop in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two models that are related, and I need to create a table that takes from both objects.

In my models:

```
class Chamber(models.Model):
    chamber_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    chamber_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ChamberProperties(models.Model):
    chamber = models.ForeignKey(Chamber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    property_value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The structure is strange, but it's too late to just add properties and values to the chamber model. I'll have to live with the fact that they are two separate models.

In my table I need the following structure:

chamber_name(obj A) - property_value(obj B) - customer(obj A again)

I tried zipped lists, but I don't seem to be able to unpack it:

```
class ChambersView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'pages/chambers.html'

    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        customer = Customer.objects.get(user=user)    
        chambers_list = list(Chamber.objects.filter(customer=customer))
        chamber_properties = list(ChamberProperties.objects.filter(chamber__in=chambers_list).order_by('id'))
        objects_list = zip(chamber_properties, chambers_list)
        form = ChambersFilterForm(request=request)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'filter_form':form, 'objects_list': objects_list})
```

If I unpack it in python it works:

```
for properties, chambers in objects_list:
            print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
            print("Property is: ", properties.property_value, "and the chamber is:", chambers.chamber_name)
            print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
```

But when I go to my HTML template:

```
<div class="card-body p-1">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr class="table-active">
            <th>Chamber</th>
            <th>Property Value</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
        </tr>
        {% for properties, chambers in objects_list %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url 'chamber' chamber.id %}">{{chambers.chamber_name}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'chamber' chamber.id %}">{{properties.property_value}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'chamber' chamber.id %}">{{chambers.customer}}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

The table comes up empty. There are no errors, no logs, the server works fine. If I just do {{ objects_list }} **outside** of the for-loop I get "zip object at " in the HTML. So I know **something** is there. I just don't seem to be unpacking it properly because if I do {{objects_list}} **inside** the for loop, again nothing shows up.

Any ideas? I would greatly appreciate any help in this matter. As a junior, I've searched around and I've seen some people override "get_context_data" for similar cases, but I wouldn't know how to do that yet or if it would be usable for this case.

Comment: Everything looks right...can you try something in your view? After you zip, can you do: `objects_list = [(props, chambers) for props, chambers in objects_list]` Not saying this is the right thing to make it work, just curious if this changes anything.

Comment: @wholevinski That worked perfectly. But I don't understand that line of code. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure _why_ that worked. That line of code though is a list comprehension that's unpacking the zipped list into tuples. Your clue of it showing as "zip object at" led me to believe the django templating might not be seeing it as an iterable or something. That list comprehension forces it to be a list before setting it in context.

Comment: I think I found it. Will post in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in python 2.7 it looks like `zip` immediately returns a list of tuples. In python 3 (which I'm guessing you're using), `zip` will return a `zip` class.

```
print(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]).__class__)
<class 'zip'>
```

Django's templating language might not know what to do with that and it bails out on even trying to iterate. Django's templating language is also very quiet when it runs into problems like that, almost sometimes to a fault IMO.

An easier way to convert it than the comprehension I put in the comments above would be wrapping it in a `list()` call:

```
objects_list = list(zip(chamber_properties, chambers_list))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it helped a lot and saved me some frustration (of which I already had quite a bit!).

And yeah, Python 3.5.3, Django 11.8.